# FLUTTER Profile picture disappears when user leaves page

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Please guys I really need help with this, I implemented an upload profile picture in my user profile page, everything works fine, the only problem is that the uploaded image disappears immediately when the user navigate away from this screen and come back to this same particular screen.

Looking forward to you awesome folks response, Thanks

This is the code that handles file selected and picture upload

```
class _UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {
  DocumentSnapshot userDoc;

  File _image;
  String _uploadedFileURL;

  Future chooseFile() async {
    await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery).then((image) {
      setState(() {
        _image = image;
      });
    });
    uploadImage(_image);
  }

  Future<String> uploadImage(var imageFile) async {
    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('chats/${Path.basename(_image.path)}}');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageFile);

    var dowurl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    _uploadedFileURL = dowurl.toString();

    return _uploadedFileURL;
  }
```

This is my user profile page screen

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('user_profile')
            .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          userDoc = snapshot.data;
          return SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.edit,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return EditUserProfile(userData: userDoc);
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              body: SafeArea(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, Homepage.id);
                          },
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_back,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: chooseFile,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 70,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                              child: Container(
                                child: _uploadedFileURL == null
                                    ? ImageBeforeUpload(
                                        image: _image, //This shows immediately when user chooses an image
//                              onTap: chooseFile,
                                      )
                                    : ImageUploaded(
                                        uploadedFileURL: _uploadedFileURL // //This shows when image has been uploaded successfully but disappears when user leaves page and come back to this page
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              bottom: 0,
                              right: 0,
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white60,
                                radius: 25,
                                child: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: chooseFile,
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.blueGrey),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      IntrinsicHeight(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              userDoc.data()['nickname'] ?? '',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                            ),
                            VerticalDivider(
                              thickness: 3,
                              width: 20,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              userDoc.data()['age'] ?? '',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        child: Card(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              ListTile(
                                leading: Icon(
                                  Icons.person,
                                  size: 40,
                                ),
                                title: Text("About me"),
                                isThreeLine: false,
                                dense: true,
                                subtitle: Text(userDoc.data()['aboutMe'] ?? ''),
                                trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 400,
                          child: ListView(
                            children: [
                              ProfileListTile(
                                leading: Icons.phone_in_talk,
                                title: 'Phone Number',
                                subtitle: userDoc.data()['mobile'] ?? '',
                              ),
                              ProfileListTile(
                                leading: Icons.add_location,
                                title: 'Current Location',
                                subtitle: userDoc.data()['location'] ?? '',
                              ),
                              ProfileListTile(
                                leading: FontAwesomeIcons.heartbeat,
                                title: 'Relationship Status',
                                subtitle: userDoc.data()['maritalStatus'] ?? '',
                              ),
                              ProfileListTile(
                                leading: Icons.people,
                                title: 'Gender',
                                subtitle: userDoc.data()['gender'] ?? '',
                              ),
                              ProfileListTile(
                                leading: Icons.looks,
                                title: 'Interested In',
                                subtitle: userDoc.data()['interestedIn'] ?? '',
                              ),
                              // Padding(
                              //   padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              //       horizontal: 50.0, vertical: 10),
                              //   child: Row(
                              //     mainAxisAlignment:
                              //         MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              //     children: [
                              //       Column(
                              //         children: [
                              //           IconButton(
                              //               icon: Icon(Icons.phone,
                              //                   color: Colors.white),
                              //               onPressed: null),
                              //           Text(
                              //             'Call Me',
                              //             style: klistTileTitle,
                              //           ),
                              //         ],
                              //       ),
                              //       Column(
                              //         children: [
                              //           IconButton(
                              //               icon: Icon(Icons.message,
                              //                   color: Colors.white),
                              //               onPressed: null),
                              //           Text(
                              //             'Message',
                              //             style: klistTileTitle,
                              //           )
                              //         ],
                              //       ),
                              //       Column(
                              //         children: [
                              //           IconButton(
                              //               icon: FaIcon(
                              //                 FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,
                              //                 color: Colors.white,
                              //               ),
                              //               onPressed: () async {}),
                              //           Text('Whatsapp', style: klistTileTitle)
                              //         ],
                              //       ),
                              //     ],
                              //   ),
                              // )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
    );
```

And finally this are the classes that handles what to display picture upload was success.

```
class ImageUploaded extends StatelessWidget {
  ImageUploaded({this.uploadedFileURL});

  final String uploadedFileURL;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CircleAvatar(
      radius: 80,
      child: ClipOval(
        child: uploadedFileURL != null
            ? Image.network(uploadedFileURL,
                height: 200, width: 200, fit: BoxFit.fill)
            : Image.asset('assets/avatar_profile.jpg'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageBeforeUpload extends StatelessWidget {
  ImageBeforeUpload({this.image});
  final File image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 70,
        child: ClipOval(
          child: image != null
              ? Image.asset(image.path,
                  height: 200, width: 200, fit: BoxFit.fill)
              : Image.asset('assets/avatar_profile.jpg'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not give a try to CacheNetworkImage?

Comment: Thanks but i have tried that, no luck still, I think the problem is each time the page is revisited the uploaded_image from firestore is null, which makes its sets the other placeholder image as its image, can't seem to figure out any code to fix that.

                                  ` _uploadedFileURL != null
                                  ? CachedNetworkImage(
                                    imageUrl: _uploadedFileURL,
                                  : Image.asset('assets/avatar_profile.jpg'),
                            ),`

Comment: Where do you set `_uploadedFileURL` in the profile widget? I do not see any such assignment, which makes it null everytime your page is opened